# How to remove missing files warning in XCode 8?

Tags: xcode, reference, warnings

I created 2 files in wrong location. Then I move them in finder and delete their reference in the project. After that I receive "Missing file" warning.

How to remove those references and remove the warning?

Comment: post screen shots

Comment: Why @HarchalBhavsar, I tell what is the message? The full message is: `/Users/myuser/ProjectDir/filexxx.h is missing from working copy`

Comment: Duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711061/xcode-8-missing-files-warnings

Comment: As I see @GauravChandarana I asked question on 22/09/2016 and the other question is asked on 26/06/2016 - in which case the other question is duplicate!

Comment: Haha..sorry, I didn't notice. By the way, it's 26/09/2016

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed them in Target → Build Phases → Compile sources?

Comment: No, I have them marked in project tree. I check your answer.

Comment: I don't see the affected files there. I see the file on proper place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I deleted files from my project and chose "Remove Reference Only" but later manually deleted the files using Finder.  I think the Source Control system got confused and I kept getting these warnings for a bunch of files.

I was able to fix it by creating a new branch in Source Control, merging the files from master and switching to that branch.  After that all the warnings disappeared.  It seemed to understand that the files are now deleted so no more warnings.

I was then able to switch back to the main branch and the warnings were still gone so I deleted the new branch and everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late with the answer, but the way I solved this issue is to discard changes for the missing files since the problem is caused by Source Control. The files are not visible on the project navigator but if you try to commit the project you will see the missing files are unchecked on the popup window.

Comment: 10x for reply. I will check, @NextDeveloper.