# Xcode 8 - Missing Files warnings

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode8

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 8 using Swift 2.3 
I have several missing files warnings. They are all related to pods that I am using.

The files that are missing are

```
*.xcscheme 
*.cpp
*.xcuserstate
*.swift
```

The pods that are showing missing files are

- Realm (~38 of 43)
- TextFieldEffects (~3 of 43)
- BEMCheckBox (2 of 43)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `pod install` ?

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé yes, I have tried pod install a few times. Deleted the pod folder and did another install.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

This is just an Xcode bug. If you delete or rename a file without then doing a commit, Xcode sees the discrepancy between the previous `git` commit and the current state of things and reports these warnings. They go away as soon as you do a `git add` that includes the file deletion / rename.

Comment: Adding the files to the index (`git add`) is enough, no need to actually commit them (more likely the project is not ready to be commited...)

Comment: @djromero Thank you for tracking that down! Would you like me to add that to my answer?

Comment: @matt sure, feel free to do it

Comment: a new commit fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Wow! Amazing work around. If anyone using source tree, staging the files will do the trick.

Comment: No. You can't be serious.
_*commited files*_
Oh. Hem... you're right.

Comment: For me, it was as easy as quickly disabling and then re-enabling source control under preferences. Xcode > Pref > Source Control > uncheck "enable source control" .... then re-enable it after. And poof! gone!

Comment: That is crazy. I was banging my head on my desk (figuratively, not literally), scouring the Xcode project to find the references to my missing files. All I needed to do was commit the changes. Has this been filed as a radar yet? I might do it just for safe keeping...

Comment: "git add ." and "git commit" confirmed

Answer (score 84):

If you don't use Xcode source control but some other git client (like source tree or terminal), you can disable source control in Xcode and then the warnings will disappear.

Xcode > Preferences > Source control and uncheck "**Enable source control**"

Comment: Does this then remove the side-by-side comparison for old commit from XCode? I'm assuming so...

Answer (score 15):

I tried all of these (and many others) but none of them worked.  After hours of trying various fixes, I found that the following procedure worked.

```
cd "project directory"
git add .
```

You will need to close XCode and reopen or future Commits may fail.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Awesome. My project got a little messy by updating the pods and the warnings just became too much... This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I solve the problem simply by this:

1. Add the culprit to the project
   [image]
2. Remove the reference 
   [image]

This cleans the internal state of XCode and the message goes away.

Comment: That indeed works. @matt's solution worked once in certain circumstances, but I have a nasty file that keeps creeping back to XCode and this is the only way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 7):

How about `commit` in `Source Control`.

You may firstly have to show Packet Contents of `"your project name".xcodeproj` and show Packet Contents of `project.xcworkspace` and then delete the `xcuserdata` folder.

If you still cannot commit because of **Couldn't communicate with a helper application** problem then under your project directory try the following:

```
xcrun git config user.name "Your Name"
xcrun git config user.email YourEmailAddress
```

*Remember to reopen the project to see the effect.

Answer (score 7):

You can resolve the issue by checking "Add and Remove files automatically" option in ***X-Code->Preferences->Source Control***

Here is the screenshot of
[Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEVsE.png)

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 8 seems to often miss `git add` the deleted/related files. To correct it, tap `Commit...` from Xcode's `Source Control` menu, make sure to check these files (which are followed by an exclamation mark !), then commit the changes. This should clear the warnings.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this problem a few times now and finally I had it after doing ugly workarounds! I sat down and tracked it until I found the reason to it and were the references are stored!

As someone already proposed it has to do with version control, well yes and no,
in some cases, it definitely have to do with poking around with files directly using the finder or whatever (but not from XCode)

Here's a quick fix that saves a lot of trouble and swear words!

Delete this file:
./.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

And the errors go away!

Comment: This worked at first, but the missing files reappeared shortly after.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case there was a .git directory in a parent directory of my project. By deleting that parent .git directory, the errors where gone.

Answer (score 3):

In my case Pods where checked into the repository generating a couple hundred warnings for "missing files". Fixed it by removing Pods from the repo :

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods/*' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by following steps:

1. Clear Derived Data
2. Discard Missing files while commit and then do commit.
3. Clean Build
4. Resolved..

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem after adding custom CollectionView cell(CustomCollectionViewCell) in the project.Same error occurred as above.
No need to delete the file instead we can.

**Rename Missing file for me it's "xCustomCollectionViewCell.xib" .**

Now the error is gone.

**Again rename the same file to original name "CustomCollectionViewCell.xib"**

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
git reset HEAD <path-to-deleted-file-that-was-causing-the-Xcode-warning>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Xcode 9.3

The solution that worked for me: Add a space in the file, save, then wait for the `!` status to change to `M`, and delete the space, save.

Sadly, with nearly a 100 files to go through, I revisited this post, and [this comment from @BennyTheNerd to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711061/xcode-8-missing-files-warnings#comment70540274_39715083), helped!

> For me, it was as easy as quickly disabling and then re-enabling source control under preferences. Xcode > Pref > Source Control > uncheck "enable source control" .... then re-enable it after. And poof! gone! – BennyTheNerd Jan 16 '17 at 7:29

Additionally though, I had quite Xcode and then open the same project, and then re-enable source control through preferences.

Hope this helps!