# Xcode keeps deleting 2 files

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I have an Xcode project using Xcode 8. I am using Swift if that helps/matters.

A few days ago after really not changing that much except a few funcs in one VC I tried to rerun my app and it had an error (I can't remember what it said unfortunately...but when I google'd it said basically that there was a file missing)

I located what the files were and just copied all changes into a blank project and deleted the file and pulled from Github a clean version and re adde the few funcs I added.

Everything was great and nice, until yesterday I noticed 2 yellow warnings.
I clicked the "Issue Navigator" and it is saying

```
TestApp project missing file

    TestApp.debug.xcconfig is missing

Pods project missing file

    pods - TestAPP.debug.xcconfig is missing
```

I realize that files just don't randomly disappear, but honestly I did not touch anything other than the Storyboard and the one ViewController File I am working on.

Why does Xcode keep deleting my files?
Is this project savable or do I need to start it over (is it corrupt?)

My project also is using Firebase.

Comment: What does Xcode say after doing a clean and a build step?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I tried that many times. I read many SO posts about holding down option while doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the files are not actually missing in any serious way. It's a bug related to use of `git` (as you say, the files came thru GitHub, so we know the project is tracked thru a `git` repository). The files were removed, but this is in fact not a problem. If that's right, then, as I explain at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715083/341994, you can solve this simply by doing a `git add` or `git commit` of these files. That will cause Xcode to become happy and the warnings will go away.

Comment: I apologize for the late bounty award, I thought marking it correct automatically awarded the bounty

Answer (score 2):

xcconfig files are used to separate out build configuration information.  Those errors are showing that you're missing entries corresponding to a debug build.

Nothing should be touching them.  Only three possibilities come to mind:

1. You didn't create debug configs in the first place, but have tried to use them somehow.
2. Your path configurations are placing these in a directory that's getting wiped out when you clean/rebuild your app.
3. The project directory is under git control and you're doing something with git that removes the files.

Here's a screenshot showing I have two configs under my Pods project, one for "release" and one for "debug".

[image]

You might try setting up your project and making sure you see the debug configs listed.  If so, see where they're kept and so on to diagnose what's going on.  Otherwise, you just haven't created them.