# The alerts in my Xcode project doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working with the Google's Ios SDK, and recently i updated the file that contained the SDK. The problem is that i get these errors saying that the files doesn't exists, but they actually exist and works fine.
These are some of the errors (there is about 80 alerts)

[image]

So, what can i do?
Thanks!

[image]

This what i tried for the last error, but the alert doesn't disappear
[image]

Comment: you have to add directory path is BuidSettings->search path frameworks->Path or '($inherited)'

Comment: can you please explain me how to do that?

Comment: click on your project file name on top -> go to build settings -> scroll down to find search path there you will find : search path frameworks . Give it a value-> '($inherited)'

Comment: I tried, but the error has not gone

Comment: Just write it completely like I mentioned you missed ' ' in that.Or you can directly add your directory path.

Comment: It didn't worked, and now i have another error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140107/discussion-between-edward-pizzurro-and-tushar-sharma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using XCode with source control integration ensure you have added those files to the repository. Once you have the files in question added/tracked in git/svn these warnings should disappear.

Also, it never hurts to Command-Option-Shift-K (clean) the project and re-open after you've tracked those files.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711061/xcode-8-missing-files-warnings) for possible approaches.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: There are many approaches. Check out a similar post on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711061/xcode-8-missing-files-warnings)

Comment: Thank you James, the errors are gone! But now, i'm getting this error (the new picture is in the question

Comment: And another question, i think i committed the files like 2-3 times. Do this files are duplicated in the project, or it is all good?

Comment: @EdwardPizzurro The files are not duplicated in the project, so you should be good. If your original question has been resolved, please mark my response as an accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah thank you, but can you help me with the new alert that i have??